# How do I fix: "Error: Dart library 'dart:html' is not available on this platform." in ios/android development Flutter?

Tags: flutter, build.gradle, dart-html, pubspec

**Was testing a UI change on my android emulator with Flutter. Emulator crashed and I got this message:**

"Error: Dart library 'dart:html' is not available on this platform.
lib/…/pages/sign_up.dart:1
import 'dart:html';"

**I also got this message:**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/calyxwozniak/dev/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1151
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command '/Users/calyxwozniak/dev/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

**build.gradle says there is an error in my flutterRoot**

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")

**Upon looking at others similar questions I have tried:**
-flutter clean
-flutter pub cache repair
-flutter pub outdated
-deleted and recreated the pubspec.lock folder
-updated dependencies Path version
-changing minsdkversion in gradle local properties

None of this resolves the error or allows me to run the emulator without it crashing immediately.

Comment: In `sign_up.dart` remove the `import 'dart:html';` line. Or switch to using: https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html

Comment: Are you using the same code file for Flutter Web? if not, then try removing the import statement for "dart: HTML",

Comment: interesting. I didn't put the dart:html import in there, but I have now removed it from sign_up.dart --still getting: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/calyxwozniak/dev/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1151. and error underline in flutterRoot def -- Any tips on how to fix this? I can't even find the line of code in flutter.gradle file it's referring to

Comment: please share the error screenshot

Comment: If this question is solved, delete it and ask a new one.